# Match part of string (SQL LIKE) In MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a field that looks like this

```
1,13,15
```

If I try to make a search to find all rows than contains "1", then it's taking all rows that have 1 inside, and not only rows that says 1, [something], but also "11","13" etc.

I've tried with a like statement and wildcards, but without luck.

Comment: what is the dbms being used?

Comment: What you try so far ? `LIKE` ?

Comment: You mean MySQL then edit your Q tags & add MySQL to tags

Comment: Instead of taking this at face value. I am curious what this field is for/of? What are these numbers for? Could there be a better database setup?

Comment: If you have a comma separated list in a DB column then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Proper solution is to fix your table so you don't have CSV data in a field. Normalize and put those values into a child table, and then your problem is moot.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MySQL, use `FIND_IN_SET`, not `LIKE`.

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', columnname)
```

But the best solution is to normalize your schema so you don't have comma-separated values in a column.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL you can use `regexp` to check such values

```
where column_name regexp '^1,|,1,|,1$|^1$'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say "1*" it finds everything that has a one and anything after that. Just narrow down your search and serach for:

```
 field LIKE "1,%" OR field LIKE "%,1,%" OR field LIKE "%,1" OR field = "1"
```

Comment: what happen if `1` is on the middle?

Comment: what happen if text field is just `'1'` no more elements so no `','`?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for "1," OR "1" OR ", 1".

Answer (score 0):

if your field is `'1,13,15'` change it to `',1,13,15,'`

and your search to `LIKE '%,1,%'`

So depending on your db you should try something like this

```
 SELECT  * 
 FROM yourTable
 WHERE ','  + yourField + ',' LIKE  '%,' + @search + ',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
select rows
from table
where field contains '1,'
```

?

Comment: Sorry--not what I typed at the end.

Comment: Select row from table where left(field,2) = '1,'

Comment: Are the results always sorted nicely like you indicate, or could they be out of order, like '3,2,1,11'  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS SQL Server, you should use `LIKE '%1%'`.